# multi create/edit in grails

Tags: grails

Is it possible to add/update more than one instance at a time? For example, we have a domain class book with bname, tile. In the gsp we are showing one form with multiple bname and title fileds. Could anyone let me know how to write a crteate/edit actions?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.  You would need to create bulkCreate/bulkUpdate pages, with appropriate controller and service methods attached.   There is nothing to prevent you from doing something like the following in a service:

```
def book1 = new Book(bname1, btitle1)
def book2 = new Book(bname2, btitle2)
book1.save()
book2.save()
```

you probably want validation in there.  bname1 etc. are the parameters you define in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Used the above code in a loop and were able to add/update records successfully

for(i in 0..booksSize) {
def book1 = new Book(bname1, btitle1)
if(!book1.save()){
flash.message = "error msg"
}
}

If there are any rows with errors/invalid data how to show data user entered along with the errors in cont/gsp? From above I'm getting only last row error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years old but I thought I would add an updated answer to this common question.

Grails provides a few handy tools to allow multi-record updates using Command Objects, ListUtils and, FactoryUtils.

Here is an example that might be used for saving multiple time card shift entries:

```
class ShiftEntryListCommand {
    List<ShiftEntryCommand> entries = ListUtils.lazyList(
            new ArrayList(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(ShiftEntryCommand)
    )
}

class ShiftEntryCommand {
    BigDecimal totalHours
    Date date
    String projectName

    static constraints = {
        totalHours (blank: false, min: 0.00, max: 24.00, matches: /^someRegex$/)
        date (blank: false, matches: /^someRegex$/)
        projectName (nullable: true, blank: true, matches: /^someRegex$/)
    }
}
```

You essentially create two command objects. One for the single instance of the form data, the other for the list of single instances. The list command object uses ListUtils and the FactoryUtils to process the "bulk" form input and each single instance still gets validated with the constraints.

You will need to import the ListUtils and FactoryUtils from the apache commons collection:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils
```

It would be used in an action like this:

```
def save(ShiftEntryListCommand cmd) {
    //other action code follows ...
}
```

Now all the bulk form data that comes to the save method is processed and validated by the command objects. To save the records you can loop through the list and call `save()` on each one or use a Hybernate method for bulk inserts. In our case we opted to loop through each record. Not sure why.

Hope someone finds this useful.